# Add multiple JSX/HTML elements if condition is true

Tags: reactjs

I am using an API for weather. In my case if temperature is less than 10 degrees I want to add some HTML elements.
`<i class="rain"></i>` The `i` tag has to be printed 150 times

```
              Here is my condition:
              render() {
                 return (
                    {items.current.temp_c <10 ? "Print 150 <i></i>" : ""}
                 )
              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `className` instead of `class`. Also, with no children, `i` should be a self-closing tag.

```
render() {
  return (
    items.current.temp_c < 10 
      ? Array.from(Array(150), () => (<i className={'rain'} />));
      : null;
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
              render() {
                 return (
                    {items.current.temp_c < 10 && Array.from({length: 150}, (e, i) => i + 1).map((item) => <i key={item}></i>)};
                 )
              }
```

try to make a array with 150 element then map it

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
  return (
     current < 10 ? [...new Array(150).keys()].map(i => <i key={i} className="rain"></i>) : <p>NADA</p>
  )
}
```

Comment: For different options for rapid list creation. Given `const addLi = (d,i) => <i key={i} className="rain"></i>`, you can use `Array(150).fill(1).map(addLi)`  or  `Array.from(Array(150)).map(addLi)`  or `[...Array(150)].map(addLi)`. Adding `.keys()`, means that you can replace `(d,i) =>` with `i =>`  If timing is critical, use a for loop.